# Square-zero extensions mod $p^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, arithmetic-geometry, deformation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\LMod{LMod}\DeclareMathOperator\Mod{Mod}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$A square-zero extensions of rings is, conceptually, a map of rings $R \to A$ such that any two elements in the kernel $I$, viewed as an $R$–$R$ bimodule, multiply to zero. That is, for $a, b \in I$, we have, in $R$,

$$a \cdot b = 0.$$

Making sense of this in various settings (classical rings, animated rings, connective $E_n$ ring spectra, …) leads to classification of such extensions by derivations/maps out of (variants of) the cotangent complex.

Now let's say a map $R \to A$ is **square-zero-mod-$p^n$** if any two elements in the kernel multiply to a multiple of $p^n$. That is, for $a, b \in I$, we have

$$a \cdot b \equiv 0 \bmod p^n.$$

Is there a classification of such extensions of $A$, say in the setting of discrete commutative algebra? Does this notion appear somewhere in literature?

*Footnote*: of course I could have said mod $k$ for any integer $k$, I chose to write $k=p^n$ to be suggestive about the $p$-adic geometry picture I have in mind, and also perhaps to make clear that a procedure like merely localizing/completing at $p$ isn't refined enough, for I'd like to see the $p$-adic topology somehow.

**Edit**: Based on the comments I realized I wasn't clear about what I meant by "classification". In the ordinary case, we can construct the cotangent complex $\mathbb L \in \Mod_A(\Sp)$ and show that understanding this linear object is equivalent to understanding all square-zero extensions. Of course the actual homotopy groups $\pi_i\mathbb L \in \Mod_A^\heartsuit$ can be arbitrarily complicated, but I'm just interested in the formal construction of the cotangent complex - this is rich and non-trivial, for example, there's a characterization in terms of Goodwillie calculus. My question is asking for a refinement of this story that keeps track of the p-adic topology.

Comment: It's a very general algebraic condition, no characterization will be available. I suggest that you add more assumptions or clarify what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg thanks. In the “ordinary” setting mentioned at the beginning, we have a general algebraic condition, and answers are available without lots of assumptions: for example, topological Andre-Quillen homology classifies square zero extensions for connective ring spectra with some boundedness assumptions on the kernel. Indeed, the assumption “being an ordinary commutative ring” is already sufficient for a precise answer. I’m looking for a cotangent complex type of classification as well in my setting, but mostly I’m curious if this notion already appears in literature.

Comment: Consider a ring $A$ in which $p$ is invertible. You are then asking to classify all surjections $R\to A$!

Comment: @PiotrAchinger surjections ARE classified by (derived) derivations, see e.g. Higher Algebra Theorem 7.4.2.7. My question is after a p-adic refinement of statements of this type. Perhaps me using the word "classification" was misleading here, I'm really talking about the usual calculus of turning derivations into ring extensions.

Comment: @MoriB. I don't understand the statement in Lurie or how it implies your claim. Say $R\to A$ is a surjection of commutative rings with kernel $I$. Suppose that $I^2\neq 0$, so that $I$ is not an $A$-module. What is the $A$-module spectrum $M$ (the target of a derivation $A\to M[1]$) corresponding $R\to A$?

Comment: @MoriB. To summarize: Unless I'm terribly mistaken (definitely possible), sprinkling higher algebra on top of a nonlinear problem will not magically make it into a linear one.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I think you might be right, I might have misunderstood something in that passage, I'll have to spend some time on it. Anyways, I think I'm specifically interested in the case when p is not invertible, perhaps I should have added that to the question.